# Property 'displayName' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Code:

```
type LolBase<T = HTMLElement> = Omit<
  React.HTMLProps<T>,
  'as' | 'selected' | 'size' | 'onChange' | 'ref'
> & {
  /** Override the root element rendered for the component */
  as?: string | React.ComponentType<any>; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
};

export interface LolProps extends LolBase<HTMLDivElement> {
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  selected?: boolean;
  selectable?: boolean;
}

const Lol = forwardRef(function Lol({ as = 'div', ...rest }: LolProps, ref) {
  const Component = as;
  return <Component {...rest}>Something</Component>;
});
Lol.displayName = 'Something.Lol';
```

Error:

```
Property 'displayName' does not exist on type '(props: LolProps & RefAttributes<unknown>) => ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | null'.ts(2339)
```

I'm a little bewildered why the `displayName` property is complaining in TypeScript?

Comment: Why would you expect your type to have a `displayName` property ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue in the [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVOEZm). Could you double check the code in your question and the code in the Playground? If the code is fine you may need to share your TS version and/or tsconfig.